# Rich snippet for website reviews

Tags: structured-data

On my website two forms of review are submitted by my customers; one for the products they purchased, and one for the service they received from us.  I add the review rich snippets as part of the Schema.org 'Product' type (along with other product information) - easy.

Now the one I'm not sure about; I display the reviews for the website/our service on the homepage and ideally I'd like it when someone searches for my website name/brand on Google that there'd also be the review stars listed for that as well as when products are searched for.  I'm not sure what schema to use for this.  My website isn't a product after all, so perhaps 'Organisation', or 'Brand'...?  What's the correct schema to use on a website homepage and so that I can list review mark-up data?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically,

The rich snippet/ review snippet is not for home page and Google discourages the use of rich snippet to showcase the homepage in Google. (Refer to this thread from Google's Webmaster trend analyst John Mueller: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69408(

You are displaying review of your website on your home page, that's fine but Google's policy is not to use rich snippet to display home page with review snippet in Google search engine page.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the http://schema.org/Service schema for and link these to http://schema.org/

> Thing > Intangible > Service
>
> A service provided by an organization, e.g. delivery service, print services, etc.

http://schema.org/LocalBusiness is also relevant.

The Site Links functionality on google is what is designed to show when a peron searches for your brand/organization name. You add this to the home page only, and demote links which you do not wish to show their (using the webmaster tools). This lets you restrict the Site Links results to pages containing ratings or reviews, although you probably want them to have the option of a few other key pages too. The nice thing is that Site Links gives you a very large rich snippet. [google instructions](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) give only 1 simple piece of JSON-LD for http://schema.org/

this is how they look, and they can integrate with AdWords to show rating underneath your brand

[image: sitelink example]